# Baking to an image using cycles with two sets of existing uvs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-baking

I would like to know how to bake diffuse indirect lighting to an image in blender using cycles.

My scene has two objects. Both objects have two sets of uv maps. The first map is for the base color texture. The second set exist and should be used to bake out the lighting. When I click bake though, it seems to only use the first uv map, not the light uv map.

I have clicked the camera icon, which I assume means "Use this uv map for baking". But that does not seem to work. How can I achieve this? I would also like to make both objects render to the same texture. Do I need to join the objects as one to do this?

Below is my node setup and the uvs for each object:

[image: node setup]
[image: object 1 setup]
[image: object 2 setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cycles baking, the Vector input of the texture being baked to has no effect(for now).  You must select the bake target UV's using the following dialogue.

[image]

It's one of those controversial design decisions but I do believe that python can access this input socket so scripters can programmatically choose the UV Coordinates.  I have not tried this though so I could be totally wrong about how that works.

Comment: Hmm I see, I think I had a few problems. It seems the blue selection determines which uv set you are using to render to. I also had to select all the objects that I wanted to render to a single texture. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed in one of the images that you posted above that you did not select the UVmap for the normal map node.  You should do that as well to avoid any confusion.  You can see the empty field right below where it says 'Tangent Space'.

Comment: The blue line should determine which one you see applied in the Viewport, the Camera Icon should be what's baked to.  I could be mistaken about the subtleties with this because I always sync up both the highlight and the icon any time I make a change there.  I never leave one highlighted with the other having the Icon activated.  That seems ambiguous and confusing to me.